# Truffle Test Library - TypeError: Member not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in library

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-test

Can somebody confirm this behavior and provide a solution?
Using `truffle test` I get the error message `Member "functionName" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in library A`. Is it because I am trying to write a test for a library?

A.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;
library A{
    function functionName(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns(bool){
        return (a == b);
    }
}
```

TestA.sol

```
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/A.sol";

contract TestA {
  function test_functionName() {
    A a = A(DeployedAddresses.A());

    bool expected = false;
    Assert.equal(a.functionName(1, 0), expected, "Comparing: 1 is not 0");
  }
}
```

deploy_contracts.js

```
var A = artifacts.require("A");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(A);
};
```

Comment: What is your migration script?

Comment: @Ismael I updated the info. The contract is migrating fine.

Comment: Problem seems to be fixed since Truffle v4.1.8 (core: 4.1.9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should try to import as:-
import { A } from "../contracts/A.sol";
And use A.functionName(). Because in solidity "library" are special type of contracts that specially use to program a reusable piece of code. You can think of this as static function in any OOP language.
May this will help you.

Comment: Wow! Changing the way of importing a library actually solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to change the import line, you only need to change `a.functionName()` by `A.functionName()`